# Applications menu indicator keeps showing when deactivated

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, indicator, gnome-shell-extension, appmenu

This morning I went to the [Gnome extensions website](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/) to update my extensions. However, when I upgraded the "Applications Menu" extensions I got an error message and it automatically uninstalled.

[image]

The problem is that now the Application Menu Indicator keeps showing no matter is disabled in the Tweeks menu.

[image]

I also tried to restart the session and the computer but nothing happens.

Gnome  3.28.2
Ubuntu 18.04

**Edit 1:**
This is what happens when I enter in the terminal:

```
sudo rm -r '/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions'
```

Details:  [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX0lh.png) - [Before the restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK4o2.png) - [After the restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61tFI.png) (Hasn't worked yet).

**Edit 2:**

```
gnome-shell-extension-tool -d apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

I entered this code in the terminal, here's an image [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz35c.png) / [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq6Gi.png) the restart. It actually worked, Thanks.

Comment: Why did you do that?! Why did you delete the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` folder? I asked you to delete the *folder associated to the extension* from the `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` directory!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension threw an error during an update, but it doesn't seem it was disabled or removed. To disable the extension run the following command in Terminal

```
gnome-shell-extension-tool -d apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

To remove it completely, go to your `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` directory and delete the folder associated to the extension, i.e. a folder titled `apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com`. Then restart your GNOME Shell or re-login or reboot your system.

**Note:** The option you see in the Tweaks app (as in the [second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA6Dj.png)) titled '*Application Menu*' is **not** for the '*Applications Menu*' extension (mind the extra '*s*').
The option is to dictate whether the *menu of an application* would appear *in the application window title-bar* or the *global top-bar* (bottom one in your case). When it's turned *off*, the menu should appear in the window title-bar. So the option is working as intended as the menu appears in your Tweaks window title-bar (application icon at the left end, before the '*search*' icon).

Comment: pomsky MVP. Here's a TL;DR of the problem and solution.  Appmenu indicator is bugged after updating some gnome-extension plugins. Solution:     gnome-shell-extension-tool -d apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com  and then restart.